Weird in timeline panel header in Blender 4.2: no play button, frame range, etc
Maybe this is a stupid question.
The timeline panel header is weird in my Blender 4.2. There is no play button, frame range, etc. The screenshot is as follows:

How can I make it like this as it is in the manual?

I appreciate any help you can provide.
UPDATE
The Addons installed is as follows:


I can't see anything like that in my Blender 4.2, the options visible in your screenshot simply do not exist in the default Timeline Editor. There seems to be the option to change the mode to "Timeline" just like you can switch modes in the Dopesheet Editor, while the original Timeline Editor only has one mode. Also this "Summary" button does not exist in the orginal timeline. Are you sure you do not have some custom extension/addon installed? If so it's hard to help when we do not know what this is (and external addons are off-topic here). Maybe you can switch the mode to "Playback"?

@GordonBrinkmann Thank you for your help. I've added the addon dialog screenshot to the question.

Sorry, I have no idea for example what the "LaughingLeader Helpers" should be. I only find something like that for Blender 2.79 so I don't know what that does. Maybe you could try to do some basic testing yourself? Disable all addons and see if this changes anything. Apart from that, is that the official 4.2 release from blender.org or some custom build or experimental branch?

@GordonBrinkmann It's an official release that was downloaded from blender.org. BTW, I've installed previous versions, too.

So, did you try getting rid of all addons to check if that's something causing this? Because I have here versions 4.2.2, 4.1.1, 4.0.2, 3.6.9 and 2.83.20, and all of them are more or less the same default layout like shown in your second screenshot. Or you could try File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings - but of course then all your custom settings will be gone without the option to undo this.

@GordonBrinkmann Loading factory settings didn't help. Uninstalling LaughingLeader Helpers also didn't help. I'll try removing all addons later. BTW, I'm a very casual hobby user and I think I didn't install any esoteric addons (maybe I'm wrong).

@GordonBrinkmann Issue was resolved. Please see my answer. I don't know the exact reason.

The timeline panel header had returned to normal when I launched Blender today. Maybe loading factory settings worked, not immediately, but sometime after exiting Blender.
